# How to send XSLT array to template

Tags: arrays, xml, templates, xslt-1.0

I need to take a data array from one node in XML and then use in XSL template.
Input data look like this:

```xml
<InpData>
 <period number="1">
   <Storage>
     <Item weight="10.5" height="5" width="15" length="20"/>
     <Item weight="20.75" height="4.5" width="7.3" length="18"/>
     <Item weight="10.5" height="5" width="15" length="20"/>
   </Storage>
   <Transportation>
     <Items>
        <Item>
          <DestRegion value="5"/>
          <Sender name="Smith" company="BlueSky" />
          <Date day="03" month="03" year="2017" />  
        <Item/>
        <Item>
          <DestRegion value="6"/>
          <Sender name="Pith" company="BlueSky" />
          <Date day="03" month="03" year="2017" />  
        <Item/>
        <Item>
          <DestRegion value="5"/>
          <Sender name="Bill" company="BlueSky" />
          <Date day="03" month="03" year="2017" />  
        <Item/>
     <Items/>
   </Transportation>
 <period/>
 <period number="2">
 <period/>
</InpData>
```

And I need to combine nodes  and  to have output xml like that:

```xml
<period number="1">
<Items>
   <Item weight="10.5" senderName="Smith"/>
   <Item weight="20.75" senderName="Pith"/>
   <Item weight="10.5" senderName="Bill"/>
<Items/>
<period/>
```

I made XSLT script:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="period">
  <xsl:variable name="weight" select="Storage/Item/@weight"></xsl:variable>

   <period number="{@number}">
    <Items>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Transportation/Items/Item"> 
    <xsl:with-param name="weight_1">
      <xsl:value-of select="$weight" />
    </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Items>
   </period>
</xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Transportation/Items/Item">
   <xsl:param name="weight_1"/>
   <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"></xsl:variable>
    <Item weight="{$weight_1[$pos]}" senderName="{Sender/@name}">
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

But it doesn't work properly. I can send to template for example  and it works if I will use just $weight_1 without indexes in the template. But I cannot use  $weight_1[$pos] in the template.

Please tell me how can I use the array weight in XSLT properly?

Comment: Your input is not XML: `<Items/>` is not an end-tag.

Comment: Sorry, bad example. In fact, question if how to make an array weight work as array in template "Transportation/Items/Item". It's the only thing that doesnt work in my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="period">
    <period number="{@number}">
        <Items>
            <xsl:for-each select="Storage/Item">
                <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                <Item weight="{@weight}" senderName="{../../Transportation/Items/Item[$i]/Sender/@name}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Items>
    </period>
</xsl:template>
```

(assuming that the only thing that links the items is their position in their parent element).

---

### Added:

To do it the way you have started, you'd need to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/InpData">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="period"/> 
    </root> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="period">
    <period number="{@number}">
        <Items>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Transportation/Items/Item"> 
                <xsl:with-param name="weights" select="Storage/Item/@weight"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Items>
    </period>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:param name="weights"/>
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <Item weight="{$weights[$i]}" senderName="{Sender/@name}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it should work, but I made just a simplified example for my question. In fact XML more complicated so using a template was good idea. But if I couldn't use an array in template I'll try your way.

Comment: I tried your way and it worked! And the code looks much better than before! Thank you one more time!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "array" - there are no arrays in XML or XSLT. I have added another option that basically finishes what you have started.